# Facebook like_count of my own page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get the fan_count of my own facebook page.

Do do this I send a call to

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/?id=SITENAME&fields=fan_count&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET`

but I keep getting the following error:

"Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook."

But I read that it should be possible to get data from my own page without review.
Or am I getting something wrong with the acces token? Should this be something else? Like the page access token?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this needs to be a page access token or a user token of a page admin.

Comment: Is there a way to get this token with the php sdk or how should I get it? It seems there were quite some changes after Mai 1st this year...

Comment: No, the general process of acquiring tokens has not changed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: I guess we have a generall thinking problem here. We want to get the fan_count from our own page without a user to log in. Do we really need a user to log in to get a page access token?

Comment: Not the website user ... but one of _you_, the page admins, of course has to grant the necessary permission at some point - and granting permissions is done via login.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this way.